# using inheritance inside a namespace

Tags: javascript, oop

Inside a namespace, i have two object definitions (AKA: "classes").

¿How can I make one class inherit from another inside the namespace?

First, I tried with this:

```
var ns = { // the namespace
    OneClass : function() { 
        console.log("Instance of OneClass has been constructed");
        this.foo = ":)";
    },

    Inherited : function() {
        this.anotherFoo = "):";
    },

    Inherited.prototype : new this.OneClass,
    Inherited.prototype.constructor = this.Inherited
};
```

but this gives an error on the 11th line: `SyntaxError: missing : after property id`

So I changed the code to this, and it worked:

```
var ns = { // the namespace
    OneClass : function() { 
        console.log("Instance of OneClass has been constructed");
        this.foo = ":)";
    }

    Inherited : function() {
        this.anotherFoo = "):";
    }
};

ns.Inherited.prototype = new ns.OneClass();
ns.Inherited.prototype.constructor = ns.Inherited;
```

anyway, I don't like this solution, because the inheritance declaration must be declared at the end of the namespace, this makes the code "messy".

So I'd rather to have the inheritance declaration as close as possible from the Inherited object definition.

Comment: Use the module pattern.

Comment: thanks Bergi! reading it from here. http://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/ it is a very usefull information